# How to remove element from multidimensional cakephp session

Tags: session, cakephp-3.0

I am working on eCommerce website where is stored all cart product in session that is working perfectly.
Here are debug of cart session.

```
debug($this->request->getsession()->read('cart'));

[
    (int) 1 => [
        (int) 0 => [
            'id' => (int) 1,
            'picture' => '1_1.webp',
            'sku' => 'TH447WA38OUMINDFAS',
            'name' => 'The Vanca Multicoloured Printed Strappy Top',
            'size' => 'S',
            'price' => '480'
        ]
    ],
    (int) 2 => [
        (int) 0 => [
            'id' => (int) 2,
            'picture' => '2_1.webp',
            'sku' => 'AL384WA86QOSINDFAS',
            'name' => 'All About You Pink Embroidered Blouse',
            'size' => 'S',
            'price' => '1330'
        ]
    ],
    (int) 3 => [
        (int) 0 => [
            'id' => (int) 3,
            'picture' => '3_1.webp',
            'sku' => 'RE367WA35NDKINDFAS',
            'name' => 'Renka Comfortable Black Color Seamless Summer Tops For Women',
            'size' => 'S',
            'price' => '495'
        ]
    ]
]
```

Now i want to remove any row from cart but that is not working for me.

```
unset($this->request->getsession()->read('cart')[1]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be simply

```
$this->request->getSession()->delete('cart.1');
```

you can use dot notation when accessing session arrays

you could also read and delete the data in one command

```
$cart =  $this->request->getSession()->consume('cart');
```

see the manual [**here**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html#reading-writing-session-data) and the API [**here**](https://api.cakephp.org/3.6/class-Cake.Http.Session.html#_delete) and [**here**](https://api.cakephp.org/3.6/class-Cake.Http.Session.html#_consume)